# Syntax error (1064) in MySQL statement in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert all of my data to a table I created. This is the relevant part of my code:

```
    rows_inserted = 0 
    table_name = "mytable"

    for row in ordered: # ordered is a list of lists. it contains all my data
        sql = ("INSERT IGNORE INTO %s (ID, A, B, C, D, E, F) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

        rows_inserted += cursor.execute(sql, (table_name, 1, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]))

    print(rows_inserted) # to verify that all the records have been inserted to the table
```

When I run the script on my server I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''mytable' (ID, A, B, C, D, E, F) VALUES (1, "QP123", ....
```

I also tried to wrap the columns names with backticks but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table name can not be parametrized. You have to add it in with string formatting.

```
sql = """INSERT IGNORE INTO {t} (ID, A, B, C, D, E, F) 
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""".format(t=table_name)
rows_inserted += cursor.execute(sql, (1, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]))
```

---

I'm not sure where this is documented, but you can see this to be true by trying:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = 'CREATE TABLE %s'
cursor.execute(sql, ['test'])
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error after copying your code. Do you see anything else wrong with my code? the error is in the same line.

Comment: Are you using MySQLdb as the database adapter? Does the error again say,   `near ''mytable' (ID, A, B, C, D, E, F) VALUES (1, "QP123", ....`? Could any of the column names be mistaken as MySQL keywords?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MYSQLdb. The error is the same, yes. My column names can't be mistaken as MySQL keywords, except for the `ID` one maybe but I also tried wrapping them with backticks which I think should prevent this anyway.

Comment: Try it with `{t}` instead of `{t!r}`. I think my attempt at quoting by using repr is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it works now :) what's the difference between `{t}` & `{t!r}`? and thanks for the help!

Comment: With [Python string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) `{t}` gets replaced by `str(table_name)`. `{t!r}` on the other hand would get replaced by `repr(table_name)`. With `{t!r}` you get quotation marks around `table_name`. I threw that in because I thought in general the table name might contain a space. But apparently the quotation marks added by `{t!r}` do not produce valid SQL.